# Codeplex "Application Runs" by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, codeplex

Codeplex offers a feature to display / monitor application runs. There is a [sample application](http://runtimeintelligence.codeplex.com/) for Dotfuscator.

Is there a chance to call this service from JavaScript without Dotfuscator?

[image: Application Runs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this case: I am doing this now by [using Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/intl/en/analytics/).